# need to get next Monday or Friday from a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

I have an invoice date in column A that needs to be paid next Monday or Friday whichever comes first
I need to get the expected payment date in column E

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes ... works fine

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that your invoice date is in cell `A1`

I need a temporary value in cell `B1`:

```
=WEEKDAY(A1,3)
```

Then I can calculate the payment date using:

```
=A1 - B1 + IF(B1 < 4, 4, 7)
```

**How it works**

Cell `B1` contains the day of the week of the invoice date: If the invoice date is a MONDAY = 0, TUESDAY = 1, ... SUNDAY=6

The formula: `=A1 - B1` will always be Monday (the invoice date if the invoice date is a Monday) or the Monday just gone on any other day. Then all we need to do is add some days to Monday:

- Monday + 4 = Friday
- Monday + 7 = Next Monday

Note: You can merge the calculations together, if you don't want to use a temporary column i.e.:

```
=A1 - WEEKDAY(A1,3) + IF(WEEKDAY(A1,3) < 4, 4, 7)
```

Comment: @DrvidT ,,, nice one U get +10 ☺

Comment: thanks very helpful

Answer (score 1):

for the record
someone also answered

```
=WORKDAY.INTL(A2,1,"0111011")
```

both answers works fine
thank u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).